# simplexml_load_file not a valid URI issue

Tags: simplexml, php

I am trying to read data from an xml file to import to data base.  I am running into an issue loading the file:

> **parser warning : xmlns: x-schema:#Schema1 not a valid URI**

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in XML file, not in your code.

You can also try to disable warnings by using

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Comment: Yes, I know the problem is in the file but I do not have any control over the file.  Just disabling the warnings is of no use because it is not letting me pull the data that I need.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the tag/URI?

Comment: Disabling warnings does not correct the error. I recomend you to check encoding